# python simple function error?

Tags: python, function

I have a simple function to do simple math operations. If I call this from another script using import, I get no output. If I remove `def function`, everything is working fine. What's the problem with defining this function? I'm new to Python.

```
def calci(a, op, b): 
    if op == '+':
        c = a + b
    elif op == '-':
        c = a-b
    elif op == '*':
        c= a*b
    elif op =='/':
        if(b == 0):
            print('can\'t divide') 
            c = a/b
            print('value is',c)
            return c 
result  = calci(12,'+', 12)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to return the result to the calling function or print it? The only path through your program that results in a `return` is division, and when you do this you'll never reach the `print` statement.

If you want to do both, you should dedent the part:

```
print('value is',c)
return c
```

...to the level of the `if` and `elif` statements. Don't forget to remove your testing code (`result = calci(...)` etc).

The reason is that once your code hits a `return` statement, that's it for the function — nothing else in it will be executed (not quite true, there is an exception handling mechanism called a `finally` block which is an exception to this, but that's not an issue here).

**Added**: since you want to just print it, remove the `return` statement and dedent the `print` statement.

Comment: i want to print it, not send it to function, when it din't work i tried to return value!!

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation at the end of the function appears to be wrong; the `print` and `return c` are only happening if `op == '/'`, and you're only assigning to `c` if `b == 0`. The end should be:

```
elif op =='/':
    if(b == 0):
        print('can\'t divide') # You should probably return here instead of falling through to the assignment

    c = a/b


print('value is',c)
return c
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function only returns if op=='/'.

Remove a couple of tabs from those two lines and it'll work.

i.e.

```
def calci(a, op, b): 

    ...

    print('value is',c)
    return c
```

Answer (score 1):

The indentation of the return part is incorrect, it should be lower-one-level. (This is so hard to describe... a flaw of Python's indentation syntax)

Here is the correct code:

```
def calci(a, op, b): 

    if op == '+':
        c = a + b

    elif op == '-':
        c = a-b

    elif op == '*':
        c= a*b

    elif op =='/':
        if(b == 0):
            print('can\'t divide')
            return 0

        c = a/b


    print('value is',c)
    return c

result  = calci(12,'+', 12)

print(result)
```